# Can Chronal Shift Be Used to Burn Legendary Resistances?

Tags: class-feature

I was playing in a game with friends and I was playing as a level 8 Wildemount Chronurgy  wizard
Our bard attempted to use id insinuation and the creature used a legendary resistance.

Could I have use my chronal shift ability, which allows me to force a re roll on a saving throw, to force that creature to burn a resistance?

Alternatively, if I use it on a successful save and the creature then fails the re roll, can it choose to use a legendary resistance on the re roll?

I personally feel that it is OP if I can force it to burn two resists, but I also feel it is op if it can choose to resist my re roll power as it wastes my ability.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. What game and edition are you asking about?  Is this D&D 5e?

Comment: This looks like a really good question, as soon as you tell us that you're playing D&D 5e (ideally via adding the [dnd-5e] tag) then we can reopen and answer this question for you!

Comment: Meta question for anyone willing to discuss if this should be reopened with D&D5e as tag: [Should this question be tagged as D&D5e without OP specifying it?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10085)

Comment: The conversation about our system-specifying policy has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110659/discussion-on-question-by-christopher-can-chronal-shift-be-used-to-burn-legendar).